# How to use Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am a little bit confuse about the how to use Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER.
I have inserted contacts along with some additional Data and I would like to retrieve some of those contacts.

If I'm running the following code eveything is fine:

```
Uri uri = Data.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = new String[]{Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME };
String selection = Data.DATA4+" = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {MY_VALUE};


Cursor truContactCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

Now, I would like to know if those contacts have a phone number so I added HAS_PHONE_NUMBER into the projection like this:

```
String[] projection = new String[]{Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER };
```

When running the query I got the following execption:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column has_phone_number
```

Why can I not access to HAS_PHONE_NUMBER? There is no problem with Data.DISPLAY_NAME which is in the same table. How are we suppose to use Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER then?

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Use HAS_PHONE_NUMBER is used for checking  whether an contact has at least one phone number.example:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();　　
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if(cursor.getCount()>0){
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));id
String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))>0){
//Query phone here. 
}
```

or add in projection:

```
String [] projection = {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER};
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

Yes I understand that I can use Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER from Contacts.CONTENT_URI. 
My question was how to use Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER with Data.CONTENT_URI.

If we are not suppose to access Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER from the Data table then this constante should not exist. 
And there is clearly an implicit join between Data and Contacts because I can access to Data.DISPLAY_NAME.

So why can I not access to Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER when Data.DISPLAY_NAME is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add "Data.MIMETYPE=ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE" to the selection statement.

The result cursor will include only the rows which have a phone number.

**Tip**.
There is the case: several numbers in one contact.
If you want all the numbers to be queried, add "ContactsContract.Data.DATA1" (Which means phone number) to the projection statement.

Comment: I confirmed that HAS_PHONE_NUMBER is implicitly joined as you expected in JellyBean(4.1.2) Samsung Gallaxy S3, but GingerBread (2.3.4).

Comment: dude, how do you confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem, and the only other reference to the problem I have found is another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812686/android-api-8-10-contactscontract-data-has-phone-number-no-such-column/15879928#15879928).

I am planning on writing my own `ContentProvider` to do the "join" through programmatic means. That is, do the original query against the `Data.CONTENT_URI` but without the `Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER` projection, and then requery the given contact for the actual value of `Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER`. This surely lacks the performance of an actual DB join (being an n+1-type of select), but will provide the desired/expected functionality. This extra processing could be made conditional upon the OS level in order to maintain the efficiency on correctly functioning OS versions.

Given *yulistic*'s answer above and my own experience, it would appear to be a bug in some versions of Android that this implicit join is not done. My Android v2.3.7 phone crashes with the same error you receive when `Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER` is in the projection, whereas my Android v4.2.2 tablet does not crash.

I have entered an Android Bug against the issue:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54095

Rob