# Android API 8 , 10 ContactsContract.Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER no such column

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-contacts, contactscontract, android-sqlite

The below query runs fine on my device (API 15).  It does not work in my emulator running API 8 or API 10.

Here is the query:

```
Cursor contactsCur = getContentResolver().query(
  ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
  new String[] { ContactsContract.Data._ID,
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
    ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
    ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
    Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.MIMETYPE,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE},
  ContactsContract.Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " >? ",
  new String[] { "0" },
  ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC");
```

Here is the exception that it throws:
`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: has_phone_number: , while compiling: SELECT _id, contact_id, display_name, data1, data2, lookup, data1, mimetype, mimetype, data7, data4, data8, data9 FROM view_data_restricted data WHERE (1) AND (has_phone_number >? ) ORDER BY display_name COLLATE NOCASE ASC`

Strangely enough, the following code also does not work:

```
Cursor contactsCur = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER},
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " >? ",
    new String[] { "0" },
    null);
```

It yields: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column has_phone_number`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html states that `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` has access to `HAS_PHONE_NUMBER` From interface android.provider.ContactsContract.ContactsColumns

To add to the strangeness, this query works:

```
Cursor contactsCur = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY},
    null,
    null,
    null);
```

But this one does not:

```
Cursor contactsCur = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER},
    null,
    null,
    null);
```

`ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY` comes from the same implicit join as `ContactsContract.Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER` !

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you need to use `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` instead of `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI`. That will generate the implict join for the additional columns.

Comment: changing to `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` gave me `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column contact_id`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html makes it look like `HAS_PHONE_NUMBER` should be available via an implicit join with `ContactsContract.Contacts`

Answer (score 5):

The main problem you're running into is that `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` **automatically** filters on `has_phone_number=1`.  So you can be guaranteed that everything coming out of `Phone.CONTENT_URI` *does* have a phone number.  You can then filter that down further by checking if `Phone.TYPE` is one of `Phone.TYPE_MOBILE` or `Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE` (for example) if you want to restrict what type of phone number it has.

---

For reference (note that `has_phone_number` is absent from the `data/phones` URI):

```
Columns for content://com.android.contacts/contacts:
- times_contacted
- contact_status
- custom_ringtone
- has_phone_number
- phonetic_name
- phonetic_name_style
- contact_status_label
- lookup
- contact_status_icon
- last_time_contacted
- display_name
- sort_key_alt
- in_visible_group
- _id
- starred
- sort_key
- display_name_alt
- contact_presence
- display_name_source
- contact_status_res_package
- contact_status_ts
- photo_id
- send_to_voicemail
```

and:

```
Columns for content://com.android.contacts/data/phones:
- data_version
- phonetic_name
- phonetic_name_style
- contact_id
- lookup
- data12
- data11
- data10
- mimetype
- data15
- data14
- data13
- display_name_source
- data_sync1
- data_sync3
- data_sync2
- data_sync4
- account_type
- custom_ringtone
- status
- data1
- data4
- data5
- data2
- data3
- data8
- data9
- group_sourceid
- data6
- account_name
- data7
- display_name
- in_visible_group
- display_name_alt
- contact_status_res_package
- is_primary
- contact_status_ts
- raw_contact_id
- times_contacted
- contact_status
- status_res_package
- status_icon
- contact_status_icon
- mode
- version
- last_time_contacted
- res_package
- _id
- name_verified
- status_ts
- dirty
- is_super_primary
- photo_id
- send_to_voicemail
- name_raw_contact_id
- contact_status_label
- status_label
- sort_key_alt
- starred
- sort_key
- contact_presence
- sourceid
```

Comment: You provided a lot of information which helps me . Thanks.